# CSS transition in Angular parent div height

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, css-transitions

I'm using css transition in order to create a sliding effect in my pagination. The problem is that even when I set the transitioned elements position to certain positioning the height of the containing div still changes. My CSS looks like this

```
.slide {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.slide.ng-enter,
.slide.ng-leave
{
    -webkit-transition: 2000ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -moz-transition: 2000ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -ms-transition: 2000ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -o-transition: 2000ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    transition: 2000ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
}

.slide.ng-enter {
    left: 100%;
}
.slide.ng-enter.slide.ng-enter-active {
    left: 0;
}

.slide.ng-leave {
    left: 0;
}
.slide.ng-leave.slide.ng-leave-active{
    left: -100%;
}
```

and my view

```
<div class="row slide" ng-repeat="alert in pagedItems[currentPage]">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      {{alert.attributes.subject}}
   </div>
</div>
```

here is my [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cgis3SXmuFSC5a7l2sdT?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Try using position:absolute during the transition instead of relative.

Comment: Can you be more specific or try to edit the plunker? Thanks

Comment: Look at the very first style rule on the css you posted.

Comment: This causes every row to collapse on each other.

Comment: Put all the rows in a div and move them together. Not rocket science.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't put the ng-repeat expression on the inner div other than that you're using Bootstrap and it sucks?